# Spring autowire="byType" with Java Config?

Tags: spring, spring-framework-beans

I can autowire by type and by name in the XML config in the following manner

```
<bean name="employee1" class="com.Class1" autowire="byName">
<bean name="employee2" class="com.Class2" autowire="byType">
```

But how can I accomplish the same in Java config? I mean, what is Java Config equivalent of autowire="byName" and by autowire="byType" attributes?

```
@Configuration
public class JavaConfig {

//How to configure beans here, like above?

}
```

The following code is not working

```
    @Bean
    public Company company(){
return new Company();
    }

    @Bean
    public Employee employee1(@Autowired Company company){
return new Employee();
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please look at this link https://www.journaldev.com/2623/spring-autowired-annotation

Answer (score 0):

When you just autowire via `@Autowired` annotation - it means autowiring by type.

If we want to autowire by name we need to use `@Autowired` and `@Qualifier` annotation together.

Example:

```
@Configuration
public class JavaConfig {

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("stackoverflow")
    public Company company(){
    }

    @Bean
    public Employee employee1(@Autowired Company company){
    }

    @Bean
    public Employee employee2(@Autowired @Qualifier("stackoverflow") Company company){
    }

}
```

**Updated:** Also you can use parameter of `@Bean` annotation:

```
@Bean
public Company company(){
    return new Company();
}

@Bean(autowire = Autowire.BY_NAME)
public Employee employee1(@Autowired Company company){
    return new Employee();
}
```

Please see additional information [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html#autowire--)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have added some additional info in my question, with sample code (Based on what you suggested). It is still not working. 

Also, the link you shared doesn't talk about @autowire in Java config file.

Comment: But it's deprecated